# zip folder using python without changing directory

Tags: python, zip

I want to zip a folder at x location to y location, I have written code for it. This is my code -

```
cwd = os.getcwd()
os.chdir(path.realpath(f"/y"))
shutil.make_archive(filename, "zip", file_path)
os.chdir(cwd)
```

I don't want to change directories, can I pass path of the folder I want to zip and path of the destination where I want to store that zipped folder? is this possible using python ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you wanted to archive **/location/x/my_folder** to **/location/y/my_archive.zip**:

The **base_name** is describing the **destination**, in this case location y.

The combination of **root_dir** and **base_dir** describe the **source**, in this case x.

The **base_dir** is the directory that gets added to the archive.

```
from shutil import make_archive
root_dir = "/location/x"

make_archive(base_name="/location/y/my_archive",
             format="zip",
             root_dir=root_dir,
             base_dir="my_folder")
```